# Laravel Sending Emails with Mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

Trying to follow the documentation (http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/mailgun-setup-with-laravel-5-exampleexample.html and https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail) to get my laravel instance to send emails using Mailgun. Seems to work, from the contact page, because it redirects itself to the contact page, but the email never seems to be sent. Mailgun is also not registering that it sent an email.

From Mailgun, the domain has already been verified and DNS for TXT values have been setup.

Using Laravel 5.4

```
    Mail::send('emails.contactEmail', ['header' => $headers], function($message) {
        $message->from('info@domainname.com', 'Info Header');
        $message->to('personalemailfortest@gmail.com');

    });
```

.env file is setup like so:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@mg.domainname.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=1****************************8
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

services.php

```
   'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('mg.domainname.com'),
        'secret' => env('key-f**************************e'),
    ],
```

No error messages anywhere in console or laravel.log. Not sure where things are breaking down. Not even sure how to begin troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: If you have `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` in your .env file, then what you have in `services.php` is ignored.

Comment: What should the value of MAIL_DRIVER be in this case then?

Comment: `mailgun`, it is in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write your credit card credentials when register your account?

> Accounts without a credit card are restricted to authorized recipients
>   only.

[Authorized Recipients](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients)

**EDIT**
Try this solution

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=null
MAIL_PORT=null
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=your_verified_domain
MAILGUN_SECRET=your_secret_key
```

Copy/past my own .env which work perfectly :)

In **config/services**:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],
```

In **config/mail**:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
```

Comment: No, but the email address that I'm trying to send to is in the authorized recipients as verified.

Comment: Hmm ... What say Mailguns log?

Comment: Update my answer, hope it help

Comment: i did same as you did but didn't recieve mail on the other side.

Comment: Did you get any error message on mailgun side? Did the mail sending work in local sendbox? What version of Laravel you use? I need more info to  help you

Comment: It worked! But @OdinThunder can you please explain why we required MAILGUN_SECRET even we have MAIL_USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD